# python: return False if there is not an element in a list starting with 'p='

Tags: python, list, loops, any

having a list like

```
lst = ['hello', 'stack', 'overflow', 'friends']
```

how can i do something like:

```
if there is not an element in lst starting with 'p=' return False else return True
```

?

i was thinking something like:

```
for i in lst:
   if i.startswith('p=')
       return True
```

but i can't add the return False inside the loop or it goes out at the first element.

Comment: @ScottHunter sure

Comment: Since you only know it is `False` once you have tested all of the elements, you should return `False` *after* the loop finishes.

Comment: Then put `return False` *outside* the loop, or in the `else` block. You can't be sure there are none until the end. Or just use `return any(...)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will test whether or not each element of `lst` satisfies your condition, then computes the `or` of those results:

```
any(x.startswith("p=") for x in lst)
```

Comment: Why the list comprehension inside `any` instead of a generator comprehension `any(x.startswith("p=") for x in lst)`?

Comment: I removed the list comprehension. You were wasting memory and tests. With a generator expression `any()` can *short-circuit the loop*; when the first element passes the test there is no need to test everything that follows any more.

Answer (score 5):

use `any` conditions to check all the elements in a list with the same condition:

```
lst = ['hello','p=15' ,'stack', 'overflow', 'friends']
return any(l.startswith("p=") for l in lst)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use builtin method [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check it any element in the list starts with `p=`. Use string's [startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method to check the start of string

```
>>> lst = ['hello', 'stack', 'overflow', 'friends']
>>> any(map(lambda x: x.startswith('p='),lst))
>>> False
```

An example which should result in `True`

```
>>> lst = ['hello', 'p=stack', 'overflow', 'friends']
>>> any(map(lambda x: x.startswith('p='),lst))
>>> True
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an iterator such as

```
output = next((True for x in lst if x.startswith('p=')),False)
```

This will output `True` for the *first* `lst` element that starts with `'p='` then stop searching. If it reaches the end without finding `'p='`, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's do it in two parts:

First of all, you could create a new list in which each element would be a string containing only the first 3 characters of each original item. You can use `map()` to do so:

```
newlist = list(map(lambda x: x[:2], lst))
```

Then, you only need to check if `"p="` is one of those elements. That would be:
    "p=" in newlist

Combining both of the above in a function with a single statement should look like this:

```
def any_elem_starts_with_p_equals(lst):
    return 'p=' in list(map(lambda x: x[:2], lst))
```

Comment: `return 'p=' in list(map(lambda x: x[:2], lst))` this is not valid python syntax. Unless you put this in a function

Comment: @GarbageCollector I think the OP really means that the code is in a function, judging by the wording and the example posted

Comment: Yes I guess so. It would be better if you write the complete function in your answer to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if len([e for e in lst if e.startwith("p=")])==0: return False
```